# Matrix/array manipulation in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

```
M1 = 

     1   --> Position 1
     2   --> Position 2
     1   --> Position 3
     2   --> Position 4

M2 =

     2     1     3     4
```

I need help in coding for a simple program. I have two matrices (or arrays, samples given above) and I want to update `M2` according to `M1`.

For instance, whatever number is present in `M1` third position gets updated in every index of `M2` where number 3 is present. And the same goes for all positions of `M2`.

So, my desired result would be like this: `M2 = [2 1 1 2]`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/361588-sort-a-matrix-with-another-matrix

Comment: @Hazem : Thanks..but this isn't what i have mentioned. i want to replace the numbers in M2 according to M1, not sort them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a simple [indexing operation](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
M2 = M1(M2);
```

Comment: @GavanpreetSingh: Happy to help. Don't forget that you can mark answers as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
for i = 1:length(M1)
    M2(M2 == i) = M1(i);
end
```

`M2 == i` uses the logic equality operator `==`, and it returns a vector of the same size of M2 with ones in the positions where the elements are equal to i and zeros otherwise. So for example if `M2 = [1 2 2 3]`, `M2 == 2` would return `[0 1 1 0]`.

Using this vector as the index argument select only the elements where the indexing vector is 1. Following the previous example `M2(M2 == 2)` is equal to `M2([0 1 1 0])` and will select the second and third elements, which are the ones that are equal to 2.

If we now put it in a loop and iterate over all positions of M1, `M2(M2 == i)` selects all elements in M2 that match `M2 == i` and you want to assign the value `M1(i)` to those elements.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine...but i haven't understand how. Maybe you can explain a little bit if it doesn't bother you...Many thanks for code, anyway....

Comment: I tried to explain how it works. I hope that's better :)